# jquery problem:on click function is not showing the h3 title?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i have this jquery script that clicks on link `add info` then hides it and brings up a form. and when you press cancel it needs to show the h3 again, but it deosnt show it, i dont know why:

heres my working code: http://jsfiddle.net/GLqcx/2/

Comment: jsFiddle has a "TidyUp" button that formats your code properly. Use it before saving your jsFiddle demos.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$("h3").show();
```

should be

```
$("h3 a").show();
```

Comment: nice @karim79 +1 for the fastest look up optimization

Answer (score 0):

Or alternatively,

```
$("h3").hide();
```

instead of `$(this).hide()`

As you are hiding the a link not the h3 in your code.  So when you tried to show the h3, the a link was still hidden.

Answer (score 0):

In your `.addInfo` click handler, you are hiding the `<a>` with this line:

```
$(this).hide();
```

However, in your `.cancelInfo` click handler, you are showing the `<h3>`:

```
$("h3").show();
```

You'll need to change one or the other, so that you are hiding/showing either the `<h3>` or the `<a>`.

I've taken the liberty of fixing your problem and optimizing your code a bit.  Here's what I came up with:

```
$(".cancelInfo").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent().hide().next().show();
});

$(".addInfo").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent().hide().prev().show();
});
```

[Here's a demo showing that code in action ->](http://jsfiddle.net/Ender/GLqcx/4/)

Instead of using broad selectors, we are now using our knowledge of the document structure to traverse to and manipulate the correct elements.  In addition, we are only doing one selection, thus saving some time and work.